# Pros and Cons of Gaming Frameworks

Tags: language-agnostic

This question is directed to anyone out there that is just starting in **hobby** game development. The first thing that comes to ones mind is:

**Which language/framework should I use?**

---

List of solutions:

- [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/) -> **[done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22416832/2644)**
- [Allegro](http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/)
- [Apocalyx](http://apocalyx.sourceforge.net/)
- [Blender Game Engine](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Game_Engine)
- [Blitz3D](http://www.blitzbasic.com/)
- [Devkit Pro](http://www.devkitpro.org/)
- [Game Maker](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker)
- [Gosu](http://libgosu.org/)
- [IndieLib](http://www.indielib.com/)
- [jMonkey Engine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) -> **[done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1495348/2644)**
- [Microsoft Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/)
- [Microsoft XNA](http://creators.xna.com/) -> **[done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484519/2644)**
- [Multimedia Fusion / Games Factory](http://www.clickteam.com/website/usa/)
- [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) -> **[done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484511/2644)**
- [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) -> **[done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484754/2644)**
- [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) -> **[done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486035/2644)**
- [RubygGame](http://rubygame.org/)
- [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) -> **[done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18941469/2644)**
- [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)
- [Torque 3D](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-3d)
- [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/)
- Custom -> **[done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484286/2644)**

---

Answer template:

**Framework Name (Linked)**

Pros:

- Pro1
- Pro2
- ...

Cons:

- Con1
- Con2
- ...

Comment: I believe Unity is worth a look too. http://unity3d.com/

Comment: @BerggreenDK Feel free to post an answer with the pros and cons of Unity.. ;)

Comment: thanks but I dont use it myself - I've read and heard from others that it's quite nice. Lots of portability + LEGO has build a browserbased game. All you need is to install The UnityWebplayer which is few mb at the client/user and then you get access to a real 3D engine directly in the browser. Check out the FAQ etc. on the webpage, its got different licenses, modules etc. http://unity3d.com/unity/

Comment: Yeah, I heard that and it sounds amazing. I also heard that there will be an OpenGL standard for web browsers inspired by this... Hope that happens...

Comment: What a great question. I wish the other solutions were "done". I been wanting to develop a game since 1982 and started with GEV2 using Cassette Basic. That is how I got into programming.

Answer (score 9):

[Microsoft XNA Game Studio](http://creators.xna.com/)

Pros:

- Uses .NET languages; managed memory, ease of the Visual Studio environment, etc.
- Good mix of high-level and low-level
- Supports both 2D and 3D very well
- Is proven; look at the Xbox Live Arcade, all of those games are made with XNA
- Games can be easily run on a networked Xbox

Cons:

- Uses .NET languages; can't use Java, C++, etc.
- Not too many resources (i.e. books) out yet, though it is easy to learn and use so that may not be an issue
- Windows-only. Mono (on Linux) doesn't support XNA at all.
- XNA 3.0 was released less than a year after 2.0, and now we're at 3.1; frequent changes like these can hinder documentation, i.e. books get outdated quickly and many things break when upgrading a 2.0 game to a 3.0 game.
- As of 2014, [discontinued](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/185894/Its_official_XNA_is_dead.php).

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, could you add a link for every framework? Thank you very much.

Comment: C++ is very possible, not sure if mixed assemblies can be made/used. And there are XNA port efforts, some with succes.

Comment: @darthcoder well, yes and no... it's MUCH simpler than DirectX ever was, though maybe only a step up from managed DirectX (I never used it); and of course, the xbox 360 support is a highlight.

Comment: @Dykam are you sure c++ is possible? I would definitely debate it, and I can't find anything on Google to suggest it is possible...

Answer (score 8):

If you have the time, do it all yourself. It's worth the experience and you'll learn a lot, instead of how to work with framework X . ;^)

Pros

- Full Control
- Strong Learning Experience
- Consistent code between game engine and program
- Tends to be well-suited towards the application it is applied towards.
- Supports any language/environment

Cons

- High difficulty
- No online documentation
- Generally, less generic.  Harder to apply to other games.
- Harder for other people to use.
- Probably buggier than more popular frameworks.
- Not well-tested.
- Harder to get help.

Comment: +1; Nothing beats writing a framework from scratch when you're starting out with game programming; it really teaches you the fundamentals.

Comment: Nothing beats writing a framework from scratch when you're starting out with game programming. It greatly ups the chance that you'll never complete an actual game and will give up in the middle of building a framework that doesn't really fit the game all that well anyway (after all, if your first game, you don't exactly know how to build it do you).

Comment: thats typical for programmers who aim too high. "Yes I want to make the next 3d fps hit etc etc". If someone starts off writing an arkanoid style 2d game and indeed starts at the bottom (instead of relying on a prefab framework) they might actually learn how the cogs turn instead of how framework x does something

Comment: @Chaoz : Absolutely! All that matters is, YOU made it work! Its YOUR code. A simple game is running on YOUR engine! There is nothing like that! :)

Comment: @John and reinier : Of course. If someone who has never written a 2D/3D game, and aims to develop the next commercial version of Doom or Crysis or something else, its a different matter. But it is not the same for getting your own simple 3D maze or sprite-based racing or some other technically simpler game. The important thing is, you wrote it and it works!

Comment: When creating your own gaming framework ,its worth learning frameworks from other domains (Eg:J2EE's popular MVC,etc etc).So, you have some idea on how to structure your modules(also applying the same framework too).Just my thought..

Comment: You should program a few games before attempting your own framework.

Answer (score 7):

[jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/)

**Pros**

- Uses Java; managed memory, highly supported in many mature IDE's (Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.), highly portable
- Good mix and high-level and low-level
- Modern 3D scenegraph
- Built atop [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org), a very mature and well-working game library
- Very lightweight; doesn't add very much overhead
- Built in 3D model loading in a variety of formats.
- Built in modern node-based 3D scenegraph.
- Easy to use.
- Open source; constantly evolving and improving.
- Includes culling, collision checking, etc.
- Has the option to save and read its own ultra-compact, ultra-fast binary model format.
- [Full list](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/wiki/doku.php?id=complete_features_list).

**Cons**

- Uses Java, so compiles JIT and can therefore be a bit slower than C++ and other options.
- Hasn't been used in many commercial apps (and therefore not as "proven").
- Has no attached editor of any kind, everything must be done in pure code.
- Difficult to do 2D games (for that you could try [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/)).

Comment: Very promising one but the engine name could have been made more professional.but still i upvote this.

Answer (score 6):

[pygame](http://www.pygame.org/)

Pros:

- Easy to get started and create something visible.
- Cross-platform.
- Lots of open source games available to inspect the source.
- Python language's pros (flexibility, dynamic typing, strings/arrays/tuples, etc.).

Cons:

- Performance-wise does not scale to very large games (which hobby game development rarely is).
- Mostly suited for 2D, although 3D is possible.
- Difficult to distribute as closed source.

Also SDL could be inserted as pros and/or cons.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about *"difficult to distribute as closed source"*?

Comment: I guess I meant it more like "stand alone executable". Although there are py2exe and such, I haven't had good experience with them. Distributing without the source should be easily doable using just the .pyc files and distribute it with python (still bit more work than native apps).

Answer (score 5):

[OGRE (Object-Oriented Graphics Engine)](http://www.ogre3d.org/)

Pros:

- Tons of 3D features
- Cross-platform, uses DirectX or OpenGL
- Plugin architecture for even more features
- Does not try to be an everything-engine, only a graphics engine (doesn't even try to handle input, as many graphics libraries tend to do)

Cons:

- Uses the Singleton pattern
- Very hard to do 2D or primitive rendering (individual polygons, lines, etc)
- Tons of code makes the learning curve quite steep

Comment: Thank you! These are the type of answers I was looking for!

Comment: "Many config files and such are XML based" this point is wrong for a fact thus removed. Ogre has no mandatory config files (though two optional kinds are recognized) and no config file is XML based.

Comment: @Nerian "Some consider it an anti-pattern, judging that it is overused, introduces unnecessary limitations in situations where a sole instance of a class is not actually required, and introduces global state into an application." - I'm in this camp. Also see references 1 through 6 of the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Singleton_pattern&oldid=404584255

Comment: Thank you for sharing that information. I have used many times the singleton pattern in the pervasive ways that the document describes. Now I will think twice before using it again. Thanks

Comment: OGRE is a great piece of software, but it is overkill for someone starting out. I'd suggest something a lot simpler, and probably 2D. As you say, 2D is hard using this. To start out you just want sprites and simple shapes (e.g. think platformer or top down shooter)

Answer (score 4):

[pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/)

Pros:

- Low difficulty
- Cross-platform
- OpenGL accelerated graphics by default
- Further OpenGL graphical enhancements easy to add
- Python language

Cons:

- Less well-known than pygame
- Game 'loop' is a bit unconventional
- OpenGL knowledge required for advanced graphics and to maximise performance

Answer (score 3):

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)

Pros

- SDL officially supports Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, iOS, and Android
- It is used by video playback software, emulators, and popular games including Valve's award winning catalog and many Humble Bundle games.
- Open source
- SDL is written in C, works natively with C++, and there are bindings available for several other languages, including C# and Python.

Cons

- No special IDE like Unity
- A bit low-level

Comment: Being low-level is rather a desired feature, than a drawback. But it depends on project's specification and user's experience. But in general I would say it is better to be able to operate so low on resources.

Answer (score 2):

The pros of any framework (gaming, web, etc.) is that they remove the unnecessary boilerplate code you'd have to normally write.

The cons often come up later on, once you want to go beyond the capabilities of the framework it can become very difficult.  With many of the more complex frameworks, extending their functionality to make it do something it wasn't designed to will results in you having to write a lot of your own boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

> just starting in hobby game development

You should program a few games before attempting your own framework, otherwise you don't know what to put in it and how to write it. You'll end up endlessly rewriting it to "get it right", when really there are lots of good (and bad) ways of doing it, depending on what it is used for.

"Frameworks" can also be a pain, as they offer a partial solution to a problem. E.g. you just extend a few classes and boom, you have a game. But if your game doesn't suit the framework design you just end up fighting with it and hacking it. The "toolbox" approach tends to be a better approach as it just supplied functionality without forcing you too much into how you should use it. E.g. the standard C libraries are are toolbox and don't force you to structure your code in a certain way.

To start off with you have to ask yourself:

- what sort of games you'd like to write.
- what you'd like to develop for?

  - Web browser?
  - Facebook?
  - PC?
  - PC and Mac? i.e. cross platform
  - Console?
  - iPhone and iPad?
- which language you'd like to use (but this may be set by the platform you chose)

The learning curve for writing games can be quite steep as you might have to learn:

- how to program in a new language
- how a new API works
- how to do the graphics and sound
- how to debug it
- perhaps how to hook it into other system

*Don't be put off it this sounds like a lot of work!* The key to writing good games is *sticking it out* and having the determination to carry on and finish. Have you seen the film, [Indie](http://buy.indiegamethemovie.com/)?

My advice:

- **Start simple** - There is a lot to learn, if you take on too much to start with you will be scared off and think it is to hard. So...
- **Easy language** - You'll hear lots of people ranting on the internet about how great certain languages are. Well, they all have their pros and cons. Some are easier to learn that others. E.g. Python or Lua are quite easy to learn. They are scripting languages, which are a lot more forgiving and less complicated to games together with. They don't have things like pointers, memory allocation, etc to worry about.

  - Python [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).
  - Lua [has a tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaDirectory) (which I wrote!)
- **Just make a game!** - You'll hear other people talking about patterns and singletons and data driven design etc. None of that matters when you start out. You aren't trying to impress anyone with your code. People will judge you on the end result *not the code*! Trust me, some of the best games you've played on console etc have *terrible code*!
- **Use a small, well maintained library**. I'll make it easy, there are other choices, but:

  - if you want to choose Python (a good choice!) use [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html). Use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (for Java Dev) with [PyDev](http://pydev.org/download.html). Magic and free!
  - if you want to use Lua (a good choice!) use [Love](https://love2d.org/)
- **Look for other game examples** - Pygame has tons of examples and games using it. Check the license and if you are allowed, just rip the code. Patch, splice, but put a comment about where you got the code, it is polite, and may be necessary according to the license. *Don't ignore the licensing*.

  - Look at [Ludum Dare](http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/). Tons of great examples and source code to see how it is done quickly.

Then once you have made a few games consider the more complicated libraries and languages. Then you can ask more specific questions about how to solve certain problems. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

[Flash](http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/)

Flash is a great tool for those who have limited programming or art experience, but want to start cranking out a game.

Pros:

- Symbols make graphical creation and manipulation very easy
- Symbols have built-in bounding boxes; bounding boxes have built-in collision detection
- Ports easily to web
- Built-in layers and display architecture make displaying content simple
- Lots of support, documentation, libraries
- Vector art is easy to create

Cons:

- Relatively slow
- No method or operator overloading
- Requires a purchase, either Creative Cloud or buying Flash outright
- Pixel art must be ported in, which can be aggravating

I highly recommend flash if you have access to it, its one of the programs I use most often.

Answer (score 0):

Pro's for XNA in my opinion are that XNA apps can run on Xbox360 in addition to PC, and you can pick your favorite language from anything supported by the .NET Framework - which is quite many.

Comment: I know (from my experience) that to run a game in XBOX360 you must buy a creators club card. Not that this is a big deal, just a side note. ;)

Comment: Yeah, it about $99 for a years subscription, which is not that much. If you make your game for windows then you don't really have to change anything to make it work on xbox which is really good.

Comment: $99 each year to be able to install something on my own hardware? hmm, not interested for hobby developments.